# how to handle a gradient expression

Tags: calculus-of-variations

How to prove in a rigorous way that:
$$|u|=1 \implies \nabla|u|^2 = 0 \implies (\nabla u)^Tu=0$$
and then $\forall v$
$$\nabla u : \nabla((u.v)\cdot u)= |\nabla u|^2 (u \cdot v)$$

Comment: What is $u$?  I'm guessing it's a vector field here, but is it smooth/differentiable/continuous? When you write $|u| = 1$, do you mean "$|u(x)| = 1$ for all $x$"?

Comment: u is a sufficiently smoth vector field and |u|=1 means |u(x)|=1 for all x

Comment: I can see that if |u| is constant then the same is true for |u|², hence its gradient is zero.
and I think we can write $ \nabla|u|^2 = 2(\nabla u)^Tu$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Einstein summation convention:

$$\nabla u : \nabla((u.v)\cdot u) = \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}((u_k v_k) u_i) = \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} (u_k v_k) + \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} u_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(u_k v_k) = |\nabla u|^2 (u\cdot v) $$
because
$$ \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} u_i = \frac12 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}|u_i|^2 = 0 .$$